# What does all SP weapon and grenade do?

Tags: lost-planet-2

Some SP weapon have special effect like :

- Plasma Cannon SP : Shoot three bullet in one shot.
- Machine Gun SP : Automatic Burst Fire
- Gun Sword SP : +1 Melee Combo
- V-Device SP : Make all team on active area invisible.
- Warp Grenade : Make 2 way Warp point to base.

what about other SP weapons ?